# How can I change this input's value when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a program which has several textboxes and 1 button.  When the user clicks the button the value for the  textboxes changes to `how are you`.

I'm not sure how to  refer to the value  `i` for the expression `document.getElementById('text'+i).value= 'how are you'`

```
 <input name="text1" type="text" id="text1" value="textbox 1"                 
 onFocus="this.style.background ='yellow'" onBlur="this.style.background='white'">
 <input name="text2" type="text" id="text2" value="textbox 2"                             
 onFocus="this.style.background = 'yellow'" onBlur="this.style.background='white'">
```

```
function popup() {
    for( int i; i <2, i++) {      
      document.getElementById('text'+i).value= 'how are you'      
    }
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="popup()"><br />
```

I have changed the for loop part, but its still not quite working:

```
function popup() {
    for( var i = 1, i <= 2, i++) {
      document.getElementById('text'+i).value= 'how are you'
    }
}
```

Would the program work with a foreach loop like in C++ ?  First it will count the number of textboxes you have and then create a list which goes from 1 
to the total number of textboxe, then write a for loop to count the textboxes.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(var i = 1; i <=2; i++) {
    document.getElementById('text'+i).value= 'how are you'      
}
```

---

**Clarifications:**

- You need to init `i` to be `1`
- you need to change the break condition to `i<=2`

`JavaScript` is dynamic typing language, so there are no types in the variable declarations.

**The errors you had by @esailija:**

- `i` not initialized to number.
- `,` instead of `;`
- `int i` instead of `var i`
- off by one error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the word `var` to declare variables in JS.  And don't forget your semi-colons.

```
function popup() 
{  
  for(var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {     
    document.getElementById('text'+i).value = 'how are you';        
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for simplicity, I'll point out that a `for` loop that has only two iterations and one line of code inside the loop is kind of a waste of typing.  You could also just do this:

```
var str = 'how are you';
document.getElementById('text1').value = str;   
document.getElementById('text2').value = str;
```

Comment: yeah thats true..i forgot to mention that it should work for severall textboxes.. so if you have 5 or 6 of them

Answer (score 0):

- var is used to declare variables in javascript
- variable should be initialized in for-loop
- for-loop condition should be correct to ensure it loops the right
  amount of times. `< 2` would make it stop on 1.

As I understand you, you want the i variable to show in your text as well. Just add `+ i` at the end of the string. Otherwise, just remove that part.

This will loop through "text1" and "text2"

```
for( var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
  document.getElementById('text'+i).value = 'how are you' + i;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the suggestion guys, I already made the changes,  but the program still have some bugs

Comment: @user1296160 you should accept one of the answers in this question anyways because at least we have helped you with some bugs.